# How can I get data from Elasticsearch using Logstash and put it into Graphite?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, graphite

I have `logstash.conf` file, where I take data from MySQL database. But now I have to take data from Elasticsearch and put it into Graphite. There is a code of my `logstash.conf`:

```
input {
     jdbc {
            type => "some type"
            jdbc_driver_library => "sqljdbc42.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=db name"
            jdbc_user =>  "username"
            jdbc_password => "***"
            jdbc_default_timezone => "Asia/Almaty"
            statement_filepath => "sqlscript.sql"
            schedule => "*/30 * * * *"
     }
}

output {

    stdout { codec => json }

    if [type] == "some type"  {

     graphite {
        host => "some host"
        port => port
        metrics => [some.metric", "%{cnt}"]
     }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is change the input config in logstash.conf to be:

```
elasticsearch {
  hosts => "localhost"
  query => '{ "query": { "match_all": {} }, "sort": [ "_doc" ] }'
}
```

[Just use elasticsearch input for logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html).